# Spring security 6.2 JSESSIONID not returned

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security

I'm creating a Spring Boot application using Kotlin. I've configured WebSecurity in like:

```kotlin
@Configuration
class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var dataSource: DataSource


    @Value("\${cors.originPatterns:default}")
    private val corsOriginPatterns: String = ""

    @Bean
    fun addCorsConfig(): WebMvcConfigurer {
        return object : WebMvcConfigurer {
            override fun addCorsMappings(registry: CorsRegistry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                    .allowedMethods("*")
                    .allowedOriginPatterns("http://localhost:*")
                    .allowCredentials(true)
            }
        }
    }

    @Bean
    fun securityFilterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        http {
            authorizeHttpRequests {
                authorize("/auth/*", permitAll)
                authorize(anyRequest, authenticated)

            }

        }


        return http.csrf { it.disable() } .build()
    }


    @Bean
    fun authenticationManager(
        userDetailsService: UserDetailsService,
        passwordEncoder: PasswordEncoder): AuthenticationManager {
        val authenticationProvider = DaoAuthenticationProvider()
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService)
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
        return ProviderManager(authenticationProvider)
    }



    @Bean
    fun passwordEncoder(): PasswordEncoder {
        return BCryptPasswordEncoder()
    }

    fun dataSource(): DataSource {
        return this.dataSource
    }
    @Bean
    fun users(dataSource: DataSource): UserDetailsManager {
        val users = JdbcUserDetailsManager(dataSource)
        return users
    }

}
```

My `/login` endpoint looks like this:

```kotlin
@RestController
class LoginController(private val authenticationManager: AuthenticationManager) {

    data class LoginRequest(val username: String, val password: String)
    @PostMapping("/auth/login")
    fun login(@RequestBody loginRequest: LoginRequest): ResponseEntity<Void> {
        val authenticationRequest =
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.unauthenticated(
                loginRequest.username, loginRequest.password)
        val authenticationResponse = authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationRequest)
        println(authenticationResponse)
        if (authenticationResponse != null && authenticationResponse.isAuthenticated) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok().build()
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(401).build()
        }
    }
}
```

According to the [Spring Security Documentation on Persistence](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/persistence.html) and on [Session Management](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/session-management.html)

> Once you have got an application that is authenticating requests, it is important to consider how that resulting authentication will be persisted and restored on future requests.
>
> This is done automatically by default, so no additional code is necessary, [...]

The persistence docs also mention that by default;

> In Spring Security the association of the user to future requests is made using `SecurityContextRepository`. The default implementation of `SecurityContextRepository` is `DelegatingSecurityContextRepository` which delegates to the following:
>
> - `HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository`
> - `RequestAttributeSecurityContextRepository`

So I don't really know what I am missing, authentication works well, the existing user from the database is retrieved and it is authenticated. However, I don't get any JSESSIONID cookie in the response.

When I configure session management explicitly:

```
sessionManagement {
                sessionCreationPolicy = SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS
            }
```

I get the cookie, but even if I send it with the following request the server returns 403 status code.

Here are the debug logs when I call the `/auth/login` endpoint when setting  `SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS` policy:

```
2024-01-08T18:53:30.092+01:00  INFO 49558 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-01-08T18:53:30.092+01:00  INFO 49558 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-01-08T18:53:30.094+01:00  INFO 49558 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2024-01-08T18:53:30.115+01:00 DEBUG 49558 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /auth/login
2024-01-08T18:53:30.126+01:00 DEBUG 49558 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .s.s.w.s.ForceEagerSessionCreationFilter : Created session eagerly
2024-01-08T18:53:30.134+01:00 DEBUG 49558 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-01-08T18:53:30.139+01:00 DEBUG 49558 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured POST /auth/login
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=signup test 2, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, CredentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]]
2024-01-08T18:53:39.468+01:00 DEBUG 49558 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /readMessages
2024-01-08T18:53:39.470+01:00 DEBUG 49558 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-01-08T18:53:39.472+01:00 DEBUG 49558 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
2024-01-08T18:53:39.476+01:00 DEBUG 49558 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /error
2024-01-08T18:53:39.477+01:00 DEBUG 49558 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-01-08T18:53:39.478+01:00 DEBUG 49558 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: what i can directly tell you is that something goes wrong so that you are redirected to `/error` which you havnt whitelisted, which in turn will return either a 403 or a 401, so firstly i suggest that you whitelist the `/error` endpoint https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#web.servlet.spring-mvc.error-handling

Comment: also i have no idea why you are configuring CORS using MVC when this isnt a MVC application, please read the spring security docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/integrations/cors.html

Comment: and why you are not logged in is most likely because after authentication you are not setting the principal in the SecurityContext. https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/architecture.html#servlet-authentication-securitycontextholder I find it very strange why you decided as a first thing to build some sort of fully custom security login, when you clealry havnt implemented one of the standard logins that exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller does not make use of the `SecurityContextRepository`. In order to persist your authentication, you should save the `authenticationResponse`.